# ShowCursor has no effect until the mouse is moved

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to hide cursor when left and right buttons are both pressed. It turns out the my code is working as expected except for minor glitch with mouse move.

When I call ShowCursor(FALSE) cursor becomes hidden as expected. After that when I call ShowCursor(TRUE) cursor is not appearing again until next mouse move. My opinion - its just is not drawn until mouse event occurs. Is there a way to force cursor to be redrawn?

Code:

```
void SG::CursorManager::hideCursor(void) {
    while(ShowCursor(FALSE) >= 0);
}

void SG::CursorManager::showCursor(void) {
    while(ShowCursor(TRUE) <= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly how cursor work in Windows, you have to call `SetCursor(IDC_...)` to make the cursor visible immediately.

The thing is that the cursor usually set from the window beneath, as a response to message `WM_SETCURSOR`. The idea of `ShowCursor()` is that it disables/enables the `WM_SETCURSOR` message. When disabling the cursr it also does `SetCursor(NULL)` so that the cursor dissapears. But when enabling the cursor it cannot call `SetCursor(IDC_...)` because it does not know which cursor should be shown. So it waits until the next `WM_SETCURSOR` is generated, that it until the mouse is moved.

Comment: Cool clarification. But unfortunatelly this didn't worked for my case. 
I've tried SetCursor(LoadCursor(GetModuleHandle(NULL), IDC_HAND)) and also tried to set cursor position (SetCursorPos(current.x + 100, current.y);) to artificially fire mousemove - none of them worked.

I'm actually using OIS as input events library. As I know, it uses dirrect input internally. Maybe this somehow connected to my problem.

Comment: Is there a way to generate artificial WM_SETCURSOR message?

Comment: @user1480424: You can send it manually with `SendMessage()` but you have to figure out yourself the `wParam` and `lParam`.

Comment: @user1480424: Can you show us the arguments you used with `SendMessage()`?

Comment: I've tried several options:

SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (unsigned int)hwnd, HTCLIENT);

SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETCURSOR, (unsigned int)hwnd, HTCLIENT);

SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (unsigned int)hwnd, 0);

SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETCURSOR, (unsigned int)hwnd, 0);

Also i've googled simular problem on codeproject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/134455/Setcursor-does-not-take-effect-until-a-mouse-move
unfortunatelly it has no answer.

Comment: @user1480424: You can try these things. 1) Call `SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND))`. For standard cursors you pass `NULL` as the module. 2) Call `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM)hWnd, MAKELPARAM(HTCLIENT, WM_MOUSEMOVE))`, but note that you should send it to the ultimate child in your window hierarchy, as this message will _bubble_ up to the parent.

Comment: Sorry for previous message - SetCursor is actually working perfectly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM)hWnd, MAKELPARAM(HTCLIENT, WM_MOUSEMOVE)) this works for me thank you @rodrigo.